# How to send text to the server and manipulate it

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I know a bit php, ajax & javascript (and jQuery) - but since I am a bit of a begginer I need a little help to connect the dots for this easy task:

I want to let the user enter sometext (lets say: "I saw the sun, the sun is so nice and shiny") and I want to send this text to the server and then replace the word "sun" with "moon") - send it back to the user and write to him: "I saw the moon, the moon is so nice and shiny").

I just need help with understanding:

1. How do I send the text to the server using php.
2. How do I manipulate it and sends it back to the user.

I am sure there is a tutorial for it - I just didn't know how to look for it so I am asking here - to get a good start.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <?php
       if (isset($_POST['text']))  //only execute if some text were sent to this script
       {
          echo str_replace('sun','moon',$_POST['text']); //manipulate the text and print it
          die(); // stop script execution
       }
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){//when document finished to load
          $('#send').click(function(){//when user clicked on send button
            var text = $('#text').val();//get the text from input field
            $.post('',{text:text},function(data){ // send the text to the current script as a post variable called text
              alert(data); // when we received the response display it in alert window
            });
          });
        });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="text" />
        <input type="button" value="send" id="send" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thanks for the help! one question - shouldn't I close both of the inputs inside a <form> tag? if not - when do I use <form> and when I don't need need it?

Comment: You need to enclose input tags in form tag if you are planning to submit the data using http. If you are using AJAX there is no need to do that. However it doesn't hurt, and for styling and semantics you may choose to add form tags anyway.

Answer (score 1):

no ajax needed

```
<?php
if ($_POST){
    if ($_POST['name']){
        echo str_replace('sun', 'moon', $_POST['name']);
    }
}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="text" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

if you want ajax, do this

```
<?php
if ($_POST){
    if ($_POST['name']){
        echo str_replace('sun', 'moon', $_POST['name']);
    }
}else{
?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
$("form").submit(function(){ 
       $.post('<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>', {name:$("#name").val()},                                                                                                                   
               function(html){
                    $("body").append(html);
               }
       );
       return false;
</script>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>  
</body>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend.  I searched for "ajax for beginners jquery php".  There are hundreds, thousands of resources to walk you through this very thing.  Here's one tutorial that I found:

http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Try to google for ajax and jquery tutorials. Basically it would work something like this:

Get user text input and call a javascript function that will send that text to process.php page

```
//input page    
function getAjax(text){

        var $data = "sentText="+ text +";

            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'text',
            url: "process.php",
            data: $data,
            success: function(output){              
                $('#responseDiv').html(output); //output is the text echoed from the php page
                }   
        });
    }
```

on the process.php page you take that text from a $_GET variable

```
//process.php
  $sentText = $_GET['sentText'];

echo $sentText.' - some new text added';
```