# How to pass a variable to a php page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am very new to jQuery and javascript. I have an autocomplete box setup (from jQuery UI). After the user selects his value from the search box, how do I pass that value to another php page (ie getmatches.php, which will look up that value in our database). I have:

```
$(function(){
      $("#my_cell").autocomplete({
      source: "autocomplete.php",
      minLength: 1,
          delay: 0, 
      select: function (event, ui) {
          // what goes here?    

      }
     });
    });
```

Comment: PHP is server side.  Javascript and the jQuery Javascript library are client-side.  PHP can use session variables.  jQuery and Javascript cannot.  They're two different worlds...

Comment: @paulsm4 Seems he is using a Jquery plugin which handles ajax requests.

Comment: yes, I am using the jQueryUI autocomplete plugin.

Comment: @paulsm4 I don't think you read his question. He just is asking about doing an ajax call when you select something from his autocomplete. His title is just misleading.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send text to the server and manipulate it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845656/how-to-send-text-to-the-server-and-manipulate-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either attach a get param to url like this:

```
source: "autocomplete.php?param_name=" + document.getElementById("myfield").value,
```

but I think the $.autocomplete plugin function may provide API for sending parameters to backend, I think you should read documentation for it, in most cases docs specify everything you need

Comment: That's not dynamic, because source parameter is called only on load (or whenever he executes `.autocomplete()`) so let's guess is empty by default, then all requests are made to `autocomplete.php?param_name=` (yes, nothing)

Comment: yup, that was to be a simple example.. for that purpose he can bind a 'change' type event on the field

Comment: I've already got the "source:" part working. When the user scrolls down the results from the "source:" call, how can I pass that value back to another php page?

Comment: awww undesrtood, sorry, I thought that's the backend sending part. you can just run another ajax inside select: callback, just something like this: select: function(event, ui) { $.post("backend_path.php", {param: document.getElementById("myfield").value}) } and get param from php like $_POST['param']

Answer (score 0):

You can use GET parameters like so:

```
http://yourserver/getmatches.php?search=<yoursearchstring>
```

In getmatches.php, retrieve the variable.

Comment: From php you can access this parameter by `$_GET['search']`

Comment: @jcubic injection FTW. Sanitize your variables :P

Comment: I agree with Tom. Sanitize is important.

Comment: I understand the php part. How do I do the jQuery or javascript code?

Comment: Expand this to show him how to ajax the variables over, and some php code to use them and I'll +1 this (I don't feel like writing today).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Autocomplete by default is passing the value of the input to the source you've specified through GET parameter called `term`. So if you type for example *world* it will do a request to `autocomplete.php?term=world`

I highly do not recommend to do AJAX requests inside the SELECT event handler function. Unless you mean something else (like tracking that).

Comment: Using query string values in a SQL statement is not a big deal as long as you sanitize and prepare statements.

Comment: @user522962 gimme a little scope, what do u want to do with the selected value?